# Read all files from folder and edit

Tags: python, readfile

I am trying to read all fasta files from test folder and put the name of file in all headers of individual file. The code working for first file and dont proceed to second file and return error. Could you help me find bug in my code or edit it. Thanks

```
import sys, glob, os, string
header = ''
check = 0
path = "./test/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
for file in dirs:
    fp = open(file, "r")
    fpx = open('%s_output.txt' % file, 'w')
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            line = line.rstrip()
            check = check + 1
            if check >= 1:
                header = line
                fpx.write(header + '_' + file + '\n')
        else:
            line = line.rstrip()
            fpx.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Please, provide the error returned when you run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to provide the error message you are getting! I think this must fail with "File not found" because you try to open the file by name instead of path. Try `fp = open(os.path.join(path, file), "r")`:

```
import sys, glob, os, string
header = ''
check = 0
path = "./test/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
for file in dirs:
    fp = open(os.path.join(path, file), "r")
    fpx = open('%s_output.txt' % file, 'w')
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            line = line.rstrip()
            check = check + 1
            if check >= 1:
                header = line
                fpx.write(header + '_' + file + '\n')
        else:
            line = line.rstrip()
            fpx.write(line + '\n')
```